# How to read csproj xml elements in runtime?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to read specific XML elements from a csproj file (my project file), specifically the `<ApplicationVersion>` element (I'm deploying under ClickOnce - (this is not the assembly version)

Is there a runtime option to read this field? or the only option is to simply parse the csproj file as an xml file?

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Build/

Comment: @IanKemp: Thanks - i'm added the package, now i can load the csproj to a Project object - do you have examples of how to use it?

Comment: But the `csproj` file will not be in the install destenition

Comment: @Baruch: you are right, i want to read the csproj file when debugging on my dev machine - while the application is executed in the user environment, you can simply read the ClickOnce `ApplicationVersion` field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually did the following:

I used Ian Kemp's advice (comment) to install `Microsoft.Build`, `Microsoft.Build.Utilities.Core` and `Microsoft.Build.Framework` nuget packages.

And then used the following code to load the csproj file to memory and get a specific attribute value as string

```
Project project = new Project(Path.Combine(Directory.GetParent(Environment.CurrentDirectory).Parent.FullName, "<my_project>.csproj"));
Version application_version = Version.Parse(project.GetPropertyValue("ApplicationVersion"));
```